# Does Twig have equivalent 'append'?

Tags: php, html, twig, template-engine

```
{% block page %}
   <ul class="gallery">
     {% set foo = 0 %}
     {% for products in prodArr %}
       {% if foo % 4 == 0 %}
         <ul class="slides">
           <li>Product</li>
         </ul>
       {% else %}
         <li>Another Product<li> // this
       {% endif %}
     {% set foo = foo + 1 %}
     {% endfor %}
   </ul>
{% endblock %}
```

In other case I want that `li` will append to `ul` with class slides. Is this possible?

I want that my HTML will be look like this:

```
<ul class="gallery">
  <ul class="slides">
    <li></li>
    <li></li>
    <li></li>
    <li></li>
  </ul>
  <ul class="slides">
    <li></li>
    <li></li>
    <li></li>
    <li></li>
  </ul>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Twig has `embed` and `include`, but in your case you can just refactor your code like this:

```
// UPDATED:
<ul class="gallery">
    {% for chunk in products|batch(4) %}
        <ul class="slides">
            {% for product in chunk %}
                <li>{{ product.title }}</li> // assuming you have title property
            {% endfor %}
        </ul>
    {% endfor %}
</ul>
```

P.S. Unfortunately I can not test it but you will get the general idea ;)

Comment: Thanks. But not exactly. I edited my question, added example. Please look at that

Comment: @YURII please check if updated version works and let me please know

Comment: I tried, but it doesnt work, as a wanted ) It create each <ul class="slides"> with 1 li. In my opinion it must have 4 li (dynamicly) , and then create new <ul class="slides">

Comment: Updated once again

Comment: Could you explain me please your solutions? Why you use 2 for in, and variable chunks ??

Comment: Sure, first for with `batch(4)` slices full array into smaller once: [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10] => [[1,2,3,4], [5,6,7,8], [9,10]] and we just iterate throw the smaller arrays ;)

Comment: Всегда пожалуйста! ;)

Answer (score 0):

Yeah it's possible. but in that case, you must correct like this:

```
{% block page %}
    <ul class="gallery">
      {% set foo = 0 %}
      {% for products in prodArr %}
          {% if foo % 4 == 0 %}
              **<ul class="slides">**
          {% endif %}

          <li>Product</li>

          {% if foo % 4 == 3 or foo == (prodArr|length - 1) %}
              **</ul>**
          {% endif %}

     {% set foo = foo + 1 %}
     {% endfor %}
    </ul>
    {% endblock %}
```

Comment: you have just to put the <ul class='slides"> out of the if block

Comment: I want that each 4-th iteration will create new <ul class='slides">

Comment: ok i understand know. i have edited my answer. let me know if it works